# Squaring left part of equation is an equivalent transformation if the right part is zero and I limit variable to its original domain?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Is equation $\sqrt{f(x)}=0$ exactly eqivalent to a *system* of an equation $f(x)=0$ and inequality $f(x)\geqslant 0$ - meaning only those x solutions (of $f(x)=0$) qualify which being substituted into f(x) make it non-negative?

Comment: All you need is that on the range of $f$ it is satisfied that $a^2=0$ implies that $a=0$, which would be applied to $a=\sqrt{f(x)}$. For example, if $f$ is a real function, the real numbers satisfy that $ab=0$ implies $a=0$ or $b=0$, in which putting $b=a$ gives you that $a^2=0$ implies $a=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is, though that inequality immediately becomes redundant the moment you equate $f(x)$ to a square. The important inequality is the one on the RHS, namely $$\sqrt{A}= B\iff\begin{cases} A=B^2\\ B\ge 0\end{cases}$$

$B\ge 0$, in your case, is just the tautology $0\ge 0$.

For inequations \begin{align}\sqrt A\ge B&\iff \begin{cases}A\ge 0\\ B\le 0\end{cases}\lor \begin{cases}A\ge B^2\\ B\ge 0\end{cases}\\\sqrt A\le B&\iff\begin{cases}B\ge 0\\ A\le B^2\\ A\ge 0\end{cases}\end{align}